# Работа с Git и GitHub

Tags: git, github, репозиторий, git-clone

Веду разработку школьного проекта на 2х компьютерах, допустим на компьютере #1 есть версия программы А, а на компьютере #2 версия B (Версия B новее), с помощью какой команды я могу обновить программу А на компьютере #1 до новой версии В?

 Пробовал `git clone 'репозиторий на github'`, но он же заново скопирует репозиторий, а не обновит его.

Comment: `git pull origin YOUR_REPO`

Comment: Огромное спасибо вам!